# Awaiting two promises in try/catch block results in "Unhandled promise rejection"

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await

I want to await two promises that run in parallel. I do not want to await each promise serially (which works but is slower).

For that reason I thought I could create two promises first to get them rolling, say two network requests, then await them and be able to catch errors in a catch block. That assumption seems to be incorrect as I get a warning when running this example code.

- Why is that?
- How do I best run two or multiple network requests in parallel otherwise with elegant code?
- Why does Typescript not warn me that the catch-block will not
  catch rejections?

```
async function testMultipleAwait() {
  try {
    const aPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve('a'), 200);
    });

    const bPromise = new Promise((_, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => reject('b'), 100);
    });

    const a = await aPromise;
    const b = await bPromise;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Caught error', e);
  }
}

testMultipleAwait();
```

Does NOT result in "Caught error" output, instead I get

```
tsc test-try-catch-await.ts && node test-try-catch-await.js

(node:31755) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: b
(node:31755) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:31755) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Caught error b
(node:31755) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I think* I know what the issue is. Even though the promises kick-off in a concurrent fashion, you are still awaiting `aPromise` and `bPromise` sequentially:

```
const a = await aPromise; // First await this...
const b = await bPromise; // and then start to await this
```

> *This is not so much of a problem when both promises fulfill. It would keep jou waiting about as much time as `Promise.all` would, and then happily continue. That is why this problem is not so obvious at all...*

It's important to know that under the hood this try-catch is converted to a promise, due to async/await. That means that whatever comes after the the statement awaited first will end up in a promise.then callback function.

So, `const b = await bPromise` will not run before `const a` has arrived (after 200ms). `bPromise` fails 100ms sooner.

This is not to say that async/await does not pick up on the error or attach your `catch` block (as promise.catch(...)) altogether. After all, there *is* terminal output of both the node warning and your catch handler:

```
tsc test-try-catch-await.ts && node test-try-catch-await.js

1 first node sees the error     > (node:31755) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: b
2                                 (node:31755) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
3                                 (node:31755) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
4 and then your catch handler   >      Caught error b
5                                 (node:31755) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 1)
```

So de catch clause does work, but the async function does not bother to attach it to `bPromise` until after at least 200ms. Line 5 seems to confirm this:

```
PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously.
```

> *Rejection errors get thrown as soon as [the microtask queue](https://javascript.info/microtask-queue) is empty.*

The promise rejection was handled, but node thinks you're too late. You can fix this issue by using [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). This way you `await` once and your async function will catch every potential error first.

```
// Everything just as it is.. and then:

const [a, b] = await Promise.all([
    aPromise, 
    bPromise,
]);
```

---

Because I was curious I entered your code in the chrome console to see what would happen. An error log pops up for a very short period (I'm guessing 100ms). Looking at this output you can just hear chrome saying:

> *"Ah wait! It is being caught after all. Here's the message!"*

[Click for gif animation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yesm9l.gif)

[image: chrome output after running the code]

Answer (score 2):

A nice way to wait for several `Promise`s to resolve to use the [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) function. It expects an `Array` of `Promise`s, and produces a `Promise` that resolves to an `Array` containing the values that the individual `Promise`s resolved to. Furthermore, it only resolves after the last `Promise` resolves. If any of its input `Promise`s rejects, then the entire `Promise.all` expression rejects as well. It effectively "runs" all of its input processes "at the same time", emulating the classic "fork-join" pattern.

The reason you are getting that error is due to the fact that your timeout process is started *as soon as you define those `Promise`s*, and not when you `await` them, several lines later. You can see this if you log some text in the definition of one of the `Promise`s, and then log something else before your `await` expressions:

```
async function testMultipleAwait() {
  try {
    const aPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
      console.log('starting timeout');
      setTimeout(() => resolve('a'), 200);
    });

    const bPromise = new Promise((_, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => reject('b'), 100);
    });

    console.log('awaiting');
    const a = await aPromise;
    const b = await bPromise;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Caught error', e);
  }
}

testMultipleAwait();

// logs:
// "starting timeout"
// "awaiting"
```

To fix this immediate issue, you could convert those `Promise`s to functions, and then call them, or `await` them "immediately":

```
// Option 1
async function testMultipleAwait() {
  try {
    const aPromise = () => new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve("a"), 200);
    });

    const bPromise = () => new Promise((_, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => reject("b"), 100);
    });

    const a = await aPromise();
    const b = await bPromise();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Caught error", e);
  }
}

testMultipleAwait();
```

```
// Option 2
async function testMultipleAwait() {
  try {
    await new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve("a"), 200);
    });

    await new Promise((_, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => reject("b"), 100);
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Caught error", e);
  }
}

testMultipleAwait();
```

Bringing this all together, to have them run in parallel, you could try something like this:

```
async function testMultipleAwait() {
  try {
    await Promise.all([
      new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve("a"), 200);
      }),
      new Promise((_, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => reject("b"), 100);
      })
    ]);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Caught error", e);
  }
}

testMultipleAwait();
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if I can explain this in an understandable manner, here we go ...

Upon creation of the `bPromise`, the callback of your `setTimeout`-call (i.e. the promise's rejection) is "pushed" into the `timers`queue of the event loop. Now, when the event loop enters its next iteration, the promise queue does not hold the handling of `await bPromise` yet, but since the ~ 100 ms have already passed, the callback is executed and you get the `Unhandled promise rejection` error.

You need to immediately `await` the newly created promise, as the event loop's promise microtask-queue won't be empty this time and will now be executed before the callback in the `timers`-queue is processed, thus being able to actually catch the error:

```
const bPromise = await new Promise((_, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => reject('b'), 100);
});
```

I recommend reading [this](https://nodejs.dev/the-nodejs-event-loop) and [this](https://blog.insiderattack.net/promises-next-ticks-and-immediates-nodejs-event-loop-part-3-9226cbe7a6aa) to get a better grasp of how the event loop works.

Comment: Why would 100 ms have passed? The same error occurs if I set the times to 8000 and 7000. Note that switching the timing order makes the code work.

Comment: Weird, maybe I have missed something, I'll look into it - in the meantime maybe one of the pros can help you out. Sorry :)