Trouble understanding why this async/await throws an uncaught error when there is a try/catch around it
I'm looking for a deeper understanding of why this is throwing an uncaught exception.
The following code throws an uncaught exception


(async() => {
  try {
    let prom = promiseThing();

    await timeout();
    await prom;
    console.log("get here");

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
})();


async function promiseThing() {
   throw new Error("an error");
}

async function timeout() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Delayed for 1 second.");
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  })
}



The strange thing is if you replace await timeout() with Promise.resolve() or just return Promise.resolve() in timeout the error is properly caught by the main try catch. The behavior is exactly the same if you use promise chains instead of async await as well.

@trincot You can still open DevTools while you execute it to see the exception.

Even more curious, the error is reported twice: Once before the delay message, again after it.

The extra try/catch in promiseThing doesn't seem necessary to demonstrate this.

@trincot I get js:28 Uncaught (in promise) Error: an error     at promiseThing (js:28:11)     at js:14:16     at js:23:3 in Chrome DevTools

I think With a Promise, why do browsers return a reject twice but not a resolve twice? is actually a more direct dupe of this question and its visible symptom, though it is linked from the accepted answer of the marked dupe.

@JeffBowman I think the title of that one is really confusing. And while it touches on the same issue, the question is actually "why is the unhandled rejection warning removed from the console" not "why is there an unhandled rejection in the first place".

Just to add that await prom internally adds a catch handler to prom. If you do this after a timeout, event loop code processes prom as an uncaught rejection during the timeout. If you replace the timeout with promise jobs that can be completed in a single run through the micro task queue, then prom get a rejection handler before control returns to the event loop and there is no error.

@Barmar Indeed thats true, it isn't required

@Bergi No the question is why is there an unhandled rejection in the first place.

I believe @traktor has explained it.  I suspected the reason was something deeper in the event loop.  I'm still not fully understanding why though at this point, but I am currently doing some deeper diving on the event loop to see if I can understand it better.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61615834/awaiting-two-promises-in-try-catch-block-results-in-unhandled-promise-rejection does seem to be a duplicate

This question about the difference between the microtask queue and the event loop's task queue] (they're not the same) may help clear up some details.
